# C++ "Using Uninitialized Memory.. (variable name) "

Tags: c++, file, memory, file-io

This program reads the lines from the text file "penguins.txt" and copies the data into the "FeedingOutput.dat". It worked fine on a different PC but when I run it on my laptop I get the following errors:

```
 Using Uninitialized Memory 'zFeeding'
 Using Uninitialized Memory 'zPercent'
 Using Uninitialized Memory 'dFeeding'
 Using Uninitialized Memory 'dPercent'
 Using Uninitialized Memory 'wFeeding'
 Using Uninitialized Memory 'wPercent'
```

The text file "penguins.txt" looks like this:

```
Zany A 5 4
Den B 4 8
Windi C 5 2.1
```

Both the .txt and .dat files are in the same directory as the .cpp files.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    double zFeeding; //Declaring variables
    double dFeeding;
    double wFeeding;
    double zPercent;
    double dPercent;
    double wPercent;
    double zFeedingNew;
    double dFeedingNew;
    double wFeedingNew; 

    char filename[50];
    string zName, dName, wName, zID, dID, wID;


    ifstream penguinInfo; //Allows input and output for the two different files
    ofstream dataOutput;


    cout << "Enter filename containing penguins information" << endl; //Asking for user to input file name, then opening that file
    cin.getline(filename, 50);
    penguinInfo.open(filename);
    dataOutput.open("FeedingOutput.dat");


    dataOutput << showpoint << fixed << setprecision(2); ////formating the output

    //this will set the information from penguins.txt to actual variables.
    penguinInfo >> zName, zID, zFeeding, zPercent, dName, dID, dFeeding, dPercent, wName, wID, wFeeding, wPercent;


    zFeedingNew = zFeeding + (zFeeding * (zPercent / 100)); //equations for new feeding amounts
    dFeedingNew = dFeeding + (dFeeding * (dPercent / 100));
    wFeedingNew = wFeeding + (wFeeding * (wPercent / 100));


    dataOutput << zName << " " << zID << " " << zFeedingNew << " lbs." << endl; //Outputs data to FeedingOutput.dat for Zany


    dataOutput << dName << " " << dID << " " << dFeedingNew << " lbs." << endl; //Outputs data to FeedingOutput.dat for Den


    dataOutput << wName << " " << wID << " " << wFeedingNew << " lbs." << endl; //Outputs data to FeedingOutput.dat for Windi


    penguinInfo.close(); //close files and requires approval to close the program
    dataOutput.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;


}
```

I believe this may be a scope issue but I am very new to c++ so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: usually code shouldn't have horizontal bars, use another line to continue `>>` on `penguinInfo`

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
penguinInfo >> zName, zID, zFeeding, zPercent, dName, dID, dFeeding, dPercent, wName, wID, wFeeding, wPercent;
```

According to the [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `operator >>` has higher precedence than `operator,` and it's just same as

```
(penguinInfo >> zName), zID, zFeeding, zPercent, dName, dID, dFeeding, dPercent, wName, wID, wFeeding, wPercent;
```

i.e. only `zName` is set as `penguinInfo >> zName`.

You can change it to

```
penguinInfo >> zName >> zID >> zFeeding >> zPercent >> dName >> dID >> dFeeding >> dPercent >> wName >> wID >> wFeeding >> wPercent;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) doesn't do what you think it does. It simply discards the left and side, and continues with the right hand side:

> In a comma expression E1, E2, the expression E1 is evaluated, its result is discarded (although if it has class type, it won't be destroyed until the end of the containing full expression), and its side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression E2 begins (note that a user-defined operator, cannot guarantee sequencing) (until C++17).

Most importantly, it *does not* fill all the variables used in the comma expression with anything. Thus, your variables remain uninitialized (since you didn't initialize them above).

What you actually want to do is to chain the `>>` operator just like you would the `<<` operator. That would look like this instead:

```
penguinInfo >> zName >> zID >> zFeeding >> zPercent >> dName >> dID >> dFeeding >> dPercent >> wName >> wID >> wFeeding >> wPercent;
```